# How to test Cordova camera plugin on browser

Tags: cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

I'm in the process of creating a cross-platform app which makes use of the camera. This knocks out the possibility of using getUserMedia. Cordova allows for testing on a local browser if I run`cordova run browser`.

The issue is, however, that although the browser does ask my permission and even shows that the camera is in use, there is no camera interface.

How can I effectively test this point of the app, to get the picture, shut the camera, and pass it on?

Comment: you can't do that. You need to test that on a device

Comment: @BraianMellor So my only option is to develop using getUserMedia? Is there a way then that I can test if it is running in the Browser?

Comment: I'll go with no, in my experience. Even with iSimulator you'll have same problem. Testing it in device is the best way to do it (that sucks)